# Github API Python OAuth parameters

Tags: python-3.x, oauth, get, access-token, github-api

I am trying to send a GET request with OAuth in Python, but I don't know how to access my app key and secret, since it's not in my backend program.

According to this code I need four parameters, but two of them come from the app itself. Does this mean that the frontend website should have an accessible app key and secret, or do these have to be generated by other means?

```
auth = OAuth1('YOUR_APP_KEY', 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
               'USER_OAUTH_TOKEN', 'USER_OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET')
```

The authentication docs of the requests library mention the flask library frequently but that must be irrelevant to my web crawler, so I feel that I am missing some data to resolve this issue.

Comment: You talk about a get request with OAuth2, but you use OAuth1 in the example, is that on purpose?
Btw: I would either add a OAuth1 or OAuth2 tag to that question, depending on what you really want.